# why is my cookie not set , is it my localhost?

Tags: php, cookies

```
$cookie_name = 'dee[user]'; i wanted to put in a array , isit here causing the problem?
$cookie_value = 'dee[authID]';

            setcookie($cookie_name, $subname, time() + (86400 * 30), '/','127.0.0.1', false);
            setcookie($cookie_value, $authID, time() + (86400 * 30), '/','127.0.0.1', false);

            if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
                print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" does not exist...';
            }else{
                print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" value is: ' . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
            }
```

why isit my cookie not set ? it keep returning false. i was trying to set cookie array and into localhost.

the $subname and $authID , is working fine just think it as a value.